# Parsing the data on the table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table in which one column contains a range of values, and another column contains the value associated with the range of values.

```
0-0.26      3
0.27-0.78   2.9
0.79-1.31   2.8
1.32-1.83   2.7
1.84-2.36   2.6
2.37-2.88   2.5
2.89-3.41   2.4
3.42-3.93   2.3
3.94-4.46   2.2
4.47-4.98   2.1
4.99-5.51   2
5.52-6.03   1.9
6.04-6.56   1.8
6.57-7.08   1.7
7.09-7.61   1.6
7.62-8.13   1.5
8.14-8.66   1.4
8.67-9.18   1.3
9.19-9.71   1.2
9.72-10     1.1
>10         1
```

I want to create a method to accept a value that lies inside the range of values and return the corresponding value in column 2.

I can implement this using if-else, but my column is lengthy, and I have multiple tables containing similar data sets.

I'm trying to build a solution using Python with nearly zero experience. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Are your first column of numbers stepped by 0.51 or 0.50? And is your second col of numbers stepped by a constant 0.1? Better would be for you to provide a number range and a step pattern.

Comment: I guess you could binary search through it, but if it's a constant increase you should just calculate it with math.

Comment: @Aeronautix Unfortunately, the step value is not a constant. I cannot derive the range and value of a pattern.

Comment: Are the values in the second column unique?

Comment: @Mole yes values in both the column are unique

Comment: @EricJin It is not a constant increase.

Comment: What is the type of that first column? Pandas has efficient Interval handling methods, but you need to tell us how you built the DataFrame to start with. Hence the importance of providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where do you have these values that you want to parse? In an Excel table, CSV, TSV, or a TXT file? Are you wanting to parse from there? Is 9.185 a possible input value? (values outside the value ranges in your first column)

Comment: @PierreD I have updated the question with the complete data set of a file. The interval is not constant here. These are some values related to the road conditions.  I'm trying to help with my sister's project here.

Comment: @Aeronautix Currently, these are in an excel file. I am open to parsing the content from there or reading from the python file itself. 9.185 is a valid input

Comment: What does 9.185 convert to? 1.3 or 1.2?

Comment: As I said: please provide copy-pastable code that produces the DataFrame (not an image), and, crucially, provide the type of the first column. I have a very clear idea of what you want to do (and how to do it), but you need to be precise in specifying the input.

Comment: @Aeronautix 1.3

Comment: If you have rows of data that all need to be processed identically, then implement a parsing and processing function for "a row", and then loop over your data one row at a time.

Comment: @PierreD I have updated the question. The first column is a range of values and the second is the corresponding result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to import your Excel file, parse it, and retrieve your new numbers based on your number ranges. You can insert `print` statements to see every step of the journey.

To run this code, copy and paste it into a file named `num_ranges_into_vals.py`, then open your terminal and type `python3 num_ranges_into_vals.py` to run it. Make sure the Excel file is in the same directory, and change the Excel filename below in `pd.read_excel('...')` to the filename of your Excel file.

Note that you will need to install the popular Python module `pandas` and possibly a few more using the Python package manager tool `pip`, with `python3 -m pip install pandas`, etc. `pandas` is a popular Python module that everyone uses for data science, so don't be afraid to install it.

```
# "pandas" is a Python module capable of working with tabled data.
import pandas as pd

# Import Excel file, and assume your table is placed anywhere in it.
#   "header=None" is needed if there's a table title in the Excel file.
df = pd.read_excel('excel_num_table.xlsx', header=None)
# Drop rows which consist of all NaN (Not a Number) / missing values.
df = df.dropna(axis='rows', how='all')
# Drop columns which consist of all NaN / missing values.
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
# Rename the two columns to be 'x' and 'y'.
df.set_axis(['x', 'y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
# Parse column 'x' so that they are numbers instead of number ranges.
df['x'] = df['x'].str.extract('([\d.]+)').astype('float64')
# Reset orig index col so it runs from 0 to length of the table (pandas dataframe).
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
#         x    y
# 0    0.00  3.0
# 1    0.27  2.9
# 2    0.79  2.8
# 3    1.32  2.7
# ...
# etc

# Parse number using a fall-through conditional loop.
#   If first condition doesn't match, go to second, etc.
def parse_num(num):
    for k in reversed(range(len(df))):
        # If number >= 10, else if number >= 9.72, else etc.
        if num >= df.iloc[k,0]:
            return df.iloc[k,1]
    return None # Number was less than 0.

# Test some numbers.
nums_to_test = [-1, 0, 0.26, 0.261, 8.15, 9.185, 9.19, 11]
new_nums = list(map(parse_num, nums_to_test))
print(new_nums)
# Orig: [-1,   0,   0.26, 0.261, 8.15, 9.185, 9.19, 11]
# New:  [None, 3.0, 3.0 , 3.0,   1.4 , 1.3  , 1.2 , 1.0]
```

Here's an answer without you having to install anything, but requires you to export your Excel file into a CSV file. The table you've shown can be placed anywhere in the Excel file.

```
from csv import reader
from bisect import bisect_right
import re

# Works wherever you placed your table in Excel.
with open("csv_exported_from_excel.csv") as f:
    reader_obj = reader(f)
    # Remove all empty strings from each row.
    rows = [list(filter(lambda x: x!='', row)) for row in reader_obj]
# Remove empty rows.
rows = [k for k in rows if k != []]
# Get the two columns: number ranges and output values.
ranges, vals = list(map(list,zip(*rows)))
# Convert number ranges into left-edge values.
left_edges = [float(re.search(r'[\d.]+', k)[0]) for k in ranges]
# Add a "None" value for when number is below zero.
vals = [None] + list(map(float,vals))
# Bisection binary search for value given left edge values are inclusive.
def num_to_val_left_edge(num, left_edges, vals):
    return vals[bisect_right(left_edges, num)]
# Test some numbers.
nums_to_test = [-1, 0, 0.26, 0.261, 8.15, 9.185, 9.19, 11]
new_nums = [num_to_val_left_edge(k, left_edges, vals) for k in nums_to_test]
print(new_nums)
# Orig: [-1,   0,   0.26, 0.261, 8.15, 9.185, 9.19, 11]
# New:  [None, 3.0, 3.0 , 3.0  , 1.4 , 1.3  , 1.2 , 1.0]
```

Comment: Thanks @Aeronautix for the solution. I have tried the first one. df is somehow missing the first row. So I'm getting None for 0 while executing that code. Any idea why?

Comment: Please take a look here https://imgur.com/a/T2rppz2

Comment: The 0 is moved to the next row, as displayed in the above image.

Comment: Yes, my last index 19. Yes, my table is empty besides this table. The file is .xlsx format. I have opened it in Numbers app on Mac. I'm using Mac to do this work. I was told to install openpyxl to access xlsx file. Does these make any difference?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors while installing the dependencies or running the code.

Comment: `python3 is /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

python3 is /usr/bin/python3

python3 is /opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

Comment: Yes I have homebrew in mac

Comment: Seems openpyxl is using this`/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages` 
`echo $SHELL` prints `/bin/zsh`

Comment: No, I haven't used the second non-pandas code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ohmyzsh. Yes, I have `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in `~/.zprofile` . I will try to implement the second option.

Comment: `echo "${BASH_VERSION}"` is showing empty. I'm using zsh as my default shell. Ohh is this related to macOS?

Comment: The second solution is working.

Comment: Yes, the terminal is showing the output of print statements. No other info.

Comment: I have finally found the problem, I still had the title in my spreadsheet, and when I deleted the title and ran the code, the first row of data became the column names for the dataframe on import of the Excel file. The way to fix this is to add `header=None` to the `pd.read_excel` import line. Thank you for catching this error! I will update my answer to reflect the new code.

Comment: Thanks for following up and putting the effort into finding a solution to my problem. Yes, we can delete our comments

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it efficiently (*very* efficiently: 41 ms for 1 million values to bin).

First, we need to modify your conditions to make them precise (e.g., how "closed" are intervals, etc.). In the following, we transform the string of column `'interval'` into a left bound. Our convention will be that each interval is between the left bound (inclusive) and the following next bound (exclusive) or `inf` for the last interval:

```py
df['left'] = df['interval'].replace('>10', '10-').apply(lambda s: float(s.split('-')[0]))
>>> df.tail()
     interval  value   left
16  8.14-8.66    1.4   8.14
17  8.67-9.18    1.3   8.67
18  9.19-9.71    1.2   9.19
19    9.72-10    1.1   9.72
20        >10    1.0  10.00
```

Then, we can use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to efficiently sift a bunch of values into bins, and then use the desired value as label:

```py
# example
np.random.seed(0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(0, 12, 10)})

# now, do the mapping:
cutkwargs = dict(
    bins=df['left'].tolist() + [float('Inf')],
    labels=df['value'],
    right=False,
)
df2['value'] = pd.cut(df2['x'], **cutkwargs).astype(float)
>>> df2
           x  value
0   6.585762    1.7
1   8.582272    1.4
2   7.233161    1.6
3   6.538598    1.8
4   5.083858    2.0
5   7.750729    1.5
6   5.251047    2.0
7  10.701276    1.0
8  11.563953    1.0
9   4.601298    2.1
```

Note: if you are also interested to see the interval each value comes from:

```py
>>> df2.assign(interval=df['interval'].iloc[pd.cut(df2['x'], **cutkwargs).cat.codes].values)
           x  value   interval
0   6.585762    1.7  6.57-7.08
1   8.582272    1.4  8.14-8.66
2   7.233161    1.6  7.09-7.61
3   6.538598    1.8  6.04-6.56
4   5.083858    2.0  4.99-5.51
5   7.750729    1.5  7.62-8.13
6   5.251047    2.0  4.99-5.51
7  10.701276    1.0        >10
8  11.563953    1.0        >10
9   4.601298    2.1  4.47-4.98
```

And, to be really correct, we should replace the string intervals that are subject to interpretation to proper intervals:

```py
df['interval'] = df.assign(
    right=df['left'].shift(-1).fillna(float('inf'))
).apply(lambda r: pd.Interval(r['left'], r['right'], closed='left'), axis=1)
```

With this, the above becomes:

```py
           x  value      interval
0   6.585762    1.7  [6.57, 7.09)
1   8.582272    1.4  [8.14, 8.67)
2   7.233161    1.6  [7.09, 7.62)
3   6.538598    1.8  [6.04, 6.57)
4   5.083858    2.0  [4.99, 5.52)
5   7.750729    1.5  [7.62, 8.14)
6   5.251047    2.0  [4.99, 5.52)
7  10.701276    1.0   [10.0, inf)
8  11.563953    1.0   [10.0, inf)
9   4.601298    2.1  [4.47, 4.99)
```

### Speed

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(0, 12, 1_000_000)})

%timeit pd.cut(df2['x'], **cutkwargs).astype(float)
# 41.1 ms ± 600 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: using numpy seems a bit overkill when a fall-through lookup also works, but for folks who can read science python, this is a _nice_ solution.

Comment: what do you mean 'using numpy'? I use 'numpy' only to demo the solution, not as part of it. Also, depending on the number of values to process, I doubt a "fall-through lookup" will get anywhere close to the speed of this approach.

Comment: probably, but someone new to python won't understand how to generalize np.functions and performance is almost certainly not a concern. However, future visitors may certainly have a better understanding of python already and appreciate this answer.

Comment: Sure, thx. My main point was: use [`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). It is orders of magnitude faster (and IMHO much cleaner) than coding a fall-through sifter by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Your data suggests continuous intervals (at two decimal rounding) so just use a fall-through lookup, based on what each row ends on: `5.2` is greater than the end values for each row until we get to the row that ends on 5.51, so we return that row's second column value. We also observe that `>10` just means `greater than the end value of the last interval`, so we don't need that row "as a row", we just need to use its value if an input didn't match any of the real rows.

So: first you remove the last row and capture its return value, then you turn the left column "range" values into just the end values, and then you just run through the list to match an input to an output:

```py
# Remove the last row and capture its value
default_value = your_data.pop()[1]

# Get a mapped list of end values given your data
end_values = [float(r.split("-")[1]) for r in your_data]
row_indices = range(0, len(end_values))

def find_mapped_value(input):
  for i in row_indices:
    if input > table[i]:
      return your_data[i][1]
  return default_value
```

And note that this will behave in an "undefined" manner for values *between* your intervals, because your table doesn't specify what should happen for things like `0.265` for example. If your data is only ever rounded to 2 decimal places then that's not an issue, but then you'll have to make sure to catch violations of that assumption either earlier in the code, or as test at the start of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if there is no requirement to the time complexity(with a binary search this will be much faster).
This approach uses a dict to store the 2nd column as the key and a tuple to store the range associated with the key. It does some string manipulation to acquire the floats from the string in the first column. Iterates through all key - range pairs to compare the values.

```
def string_to_tuple(dictionary, string, value):  # string: your range, value: 2 column

    if ">" in string:

        dictionary[value] = (float(string.replace(">","")), None)
        return
    if "<" in string:
        dictionary[value] = (None, float(string.replace("<","")))
        return
    value_range = string.split('-')
    dictionary[value] = (float(value_range[0]), float(value_range[1]))


def get_key_of_value(_dict, value): # value: value to get the key for
    for key in _dict.keys():
        if check_if_boundaries(_dict[key], value):
            return key
    return None  # if not found


def check_boundaries(tuple, value):
    if tuple[0] == None:
        if value < tuple[1]:
            return True
    if tuple[1] == None:
        if value > tuple[0]:
            return True
    if tuple[0] <= value and tuple[1] >= value:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _dict = {}
    x = [["8.14-8.66", "1.4"], ["8.67-9.18", "1.3"],[">10", "1"]]
    for entry in x:
        string_to_tuple(_dict, entry[0], entry[1])

    print(get_range(_dict, 11))# your number to check
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use re module to extract numbers from intervals, the intervals can be two side bounded like "9.19-9.71" or single side bounded like ">10" or "<5". The csv file can look like this:
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgKQN.png)

Then you can use np.where() to take care of the if/else step so that you can get the index of the desired output in the output column. Here is the content of python file "read.py"

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import re
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', type=float,
                    help='type in an input')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
    thresholds_top = []
    thresholds_bottom= []
    outputs = []
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        # find thresholds in first column
        m = re.findall('\d+.?\d*',row[0])
        if len(m)==1:
            if '>' in row[0]:
                thresholds_bottom.append(float(m[0]))
                thresholds_top.append(np.nan)
            if '<' in row[0]:
                thresholds_bottom.append(np.nan)
                thresholds_top.append(float(m[0]))
        if len(m) == 2:
            thresholds_bottom.append(float(m[0]))
            thresholds_top.append(float(m[1]))
        # find output returning values in second column
        outputs.append(float(row[1]))

# print(thresholds_bottom, thresholds_top)
thresholds_bottom = np.array(thresholds_bottom)
thresholds_top = np.array(thresholds_top)

# compare thresholds with input
find_bottom = args.input < thresholds_bottom
find_top = args.input > thresholds_top
# print(find_bottom==find_top)

ii =int(np.where(find_bottom==find_top)[0])
# print output
print('Output is:',outputs[ii])
```

Then simply write this in the terminal to execute:

```
python read.py 9.5
```